# How to correct this text processing programme?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextProcessing
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String sentence, wordToBeTargeted, wordToBeReplaced, output;
        boolean wordToCheck;
        
        Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        sentence = myInput.nextLine();
        
        do
        {
            wordToCheck = true; 
            System.out.println("Please enter the word for replacement:");
            wordToBeTargeted = myInput.nextLine;
            
            if(sentence.toLowerCase().indexOf(wordToBeTargeted.toLowerCase()) == -1)
            {
                wordToCheck = false;
                System.out.println("This word cannot be found in the sentence!")
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter the word you would like to replace with:");
                wordToBeReplaced = myInput.nextLine();
                
                
                
            }
            }while(wordToCheck = false);
        }
    }
}
```

Write a file named TextProcessing.java that will replace all occurrences of a word in a string with another word

The expected outcome is like this:

[image]

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried so far

Comment: I have posted my code

Comment: This is not a homework-writing service, but we will be glad to help you to understand and fix bugs.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

I won't write the code out - you should still get something out of the exercise, but will give some direction. The first approach that comes to mind:

1. Split the first input on ' ' into a list
2. Iterate through the list, conditionally changing values based based on two input strings
3. As you're iterating you can either output into a new string / stringbuilder, or directly write to console depending on the requirements